# Contar las palabras de n cadenas de caracteres e imprimir la cadena con mas palabras

Tags: c

Necesito ayuda con el siguiente problema, me estan pidiendo un codigo en donde debo introducir n cadenas de caracteres y de esas cadenas encontrar su numero de palabras e imprimir la cadena con mas palabras. Al momento de hacer mi codigo si lee las cadenas y las imprime, el problema es en contar las palabras, mi logica es contar los espacios de la cadena y a ese contador sumarle 1 para tener el numero de palabras, pero al momento de imprimir la cadena y su numero de palabras, a todas las cadenas imprime "1", cuando a veces no es 1 palabra, y tambien si pueden ayudarme a saber como imprimir la cadena con mas palabras (que opcion puedo utilizar). Aqui les dejo el codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
int i,m,j,k,r,esp=0,nump,espm=0;

printf("Introduzca el numero de cadenas a escribir:\n");
scanf("%d",&m);
fflush(stdin);
char cadenas[m][30];
for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    printf("Introduzca cadena %d: ",i+1);
    gets(cadenas[i]);
}
for(j=0;j<m;j++){
    nump=0;
    r=0;
    r=strlen(cadenas[j]);
    for(k=0;k<r;k++){
        if(cadenas[k]==' '){
            esp++;
        }
        nump=esp+1;
    }
    printf("Cadena %d: ",j+1);
    puts(cadenas[j]);
    printf("Palabras: %d\n\n",nump);
    if(nump>espm){
        espm=nump;
    }
}
//Aqui imprimir la cadena con mas palabras
printf("Palabras: %d",espm);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Sugerencia #1** codificación de las variables

Los nombres que has elegido para las variables son aleatorios. Usar nombres que den idea de la función o cometido de una variable es vital, ya que así se consigue que el código sea expresivo. Usar nombres adecuados para cada variable permite que el código sea legible y eso te ayuda a detectar errores.

**Sugerencia #2** Alargas innecesariamente la vida de las variables

Crear una variable de un tipo nativo en C es algo gratuito. Al programa no le va a costar nada en absoluto crear una variable.

Por otro lado tienes que reutilizar variables para distintos usos es un peligro, ya que ante cualquier edición es probable que la variable llegue a algún uso con valores inadecuados.

Reducir la vida de las variables al mínimo imprescindible ayuda a aumentar la calidad del código y previene un sinfín de errores tontos.

Así, por ejemplo, es más que recomendable reducir la vida de las variables de los bucles al propio bucle:

```
// Mejor asi
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)

// Que asi
int i;
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
```

**Error #1** Todas las frases tienen una palabra

Esto se produce porque no estás leyendo los warnings que te salen:

> ```
> prog.c:19:26: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
>   19 |             if(cadenas[k]==' '){
>      |                          ^~
> ```

Efectivamente, vemos que `cadenas` es una matriz:

```
char cadenas[m][30];
```

luego `cadenas[i]` es el equivalente a un array `char[]`. No puedes comparar un array con un caracter, son cosas diferentes. Lo que tendrías que hacer aquí es comparar caracteres con caracteres:

```
if (cadenas[j][k] == ' ')
//             ^ posicion dentro de la cadena
//          ^ la cadena actual
```

Con este cambio ya debería contar ... pero tienes otro fallo:

```
scanf("%d",&m);
// ...
gets(cadenas[i]);
```

`scanf` va a dejar el salto de línea final en el buffer. Ese salto de línea va a ser el primer caracter que lea `gets`, y como dicho caracter hace que deje de leer ... pues hace justamente eso. El resultado final es que `gets` **no lee absolutamente nada**.

Para solucionar este problema debes eliminar el salto de línea que se queda tras la llamada de `scanf`. Nota el espacio que he dejado en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
scanf("%d ",&m);
//       ^
```

Y, anticipando una pregunta por tu parte:

> Pero si limpio el buffer, he usado `fflush()`. Mira la línea que sigue al `scanf`!!!

Cierto, has usado `fflush`, pero esto es como el que tiene tos y se rasca la nariz ... no sirve para nada.

Veamos que dice la documentación de [`fflush`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/):

> In all other cases, the behavior depends on the specific library implementation. In some implementations, flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (but this is not portable expected behavior).

Más o menos viene a decir que usar `fflush` con streams de entrada (como por ejemplo `stdin`), provoca un comportamiento indefinido. Un comportamiento indefinido es todo aquel que no está especificado, por lo que cada compilador es libre de resolver el problema como mejor le parezca:

- En unos casos la llamada no hará nada
- En otros casos el buffer se limpiará
- En otros casos perderás tus vacaciones
- ...

No uses `fflush` para limpiar `stdin`. Si necesitas limpiar el buffer, puedes hacer algo así:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
```

De momento no existe, que yo sepa, ninguna función en el estándar para limpiar este buffer.

**Imprimir la palabra más larga**

Bueno, aquí tenemos varias opciones. Con lo que tienes lo más sencillo sería guardar el índice de la palabra más larga. ¿Y cómo podemos concocer ese índice?  Pues facil, cada vez que `nump>espm` actualizamos el índice a `j`:

```
int indice_mas_palabras= 0;

// ...

if (nump>espm)
{
    indice_mas_palabras= j;
}

// ...

printf("Palabras: %d",espm);
puts(cadenas[indice_mas_palabras]);
```

Claro que nadie te está diciendo que debas almacenar todas las cadenas. El algoritmo podría guardar únicamente la cadena con más palabras:

```
int main()
{
    int num_cadenas;
    int max_espacios = 0;
    char cadena_elegida[255];
    printf("Introduzca el numero de cadenas a escribir:\n");
    scanf("%d ",&num_cadenas);
    for (int i=0; i<num_cadenas; i++)
    {
        printf("Introduzca cadena %d: ",i+1);
        char cadena_actual[255];
        gets(cadena_actual);

        int const longitud_cadena = strlen(cadena_actual);
        int num_espacios = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<longitud_cadena; j++)
        {
            if (cadena_actual[j] == ' ')
                num_espacios++;
        }

        if (num_espacios > max_espacios)
        {
            max_espacios = num_espacios;
            strcpy(cadena_elegida, cadena_actual);
        }
    }

    puts(cadena_elegida);
}
```